# removeNode doesn't work correctly

Tags: php, domdocument

I want to remove all the anchor tags that starts with '/'. this is my code:

```
$html = <<<HTML
<ul>
  <li><a href="/foo/bar1">link1</li>
  <li><a href="/foo/bar2">link2</li>
  <li><a href="/foo/bar3">link3</li>
</ul>
HTML;

$dom = new DOMDocument;
@$dom->loadHTML($html);
$tags = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');
echo 'removed nodes:<br />';
foreach ($tags as $tag)
{
    $href = $tag->getAttribute('href');
    if($href[0] == '/')
    {
        echo $tag->nodeValue.'<br />';
        $tag->parentNode->removeChild($tag);
    }
}
echo 'remined content:<br />';
echo $dom->saveXML($dom);
```

but the problem is it reminds some of them.

```
removed nodes:<br>
link1<br>
link3<br>

remined content:<br>
<ul><li>
  </li><li><a href="/foo/bar2">link2</a></li>
  <li>
</li></ul>
```

any idea on how to do that?
thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't remove DOMNodes from a DOMNodeList as you're iterating over them in a foreach loop (http://php.net/manual/en/domnode.removechild.php#90292). Though, making a queue of items to remove seems to work:

```
<?php
$html = <<<HTML
<ul>
  <li><a href="/foo/bar1">link1</a></li>
  <li><a href="/foo/bar2">link2</a></li>
  <li><a href="/foo/bar3">link3</a></li>
</ul>
HTML;

$dom = new DOMDocument;
@$dom->loadHTML($html);


$domNodeList = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a'); 
$domElemsToRemove = array(); 
foreach ($domNodeList as $domElement ) { 
  $domElemsToRemove[] = $domElement; 
} 
echo 'removed nodes:<br />';
foreach ($domElemsToRemove as $tag)
{
    $href = $tag->getAttribute('href');
    if($href[0] == '/')
    {
        echo $tag->nodeValue.'<br />';
        $tag->parentNode->removeChild($tag);
    }
}
echo 'remined content:<br />';
echo $dom->saveXML($dom);
```

**EDIT**

also you forgot close tag `<a>`

Comment: yes it works. actually I saw that page but I thought the other loop is redundant!